# Why puzzle tiles are swapping randomly rather than with just empty tile?

Tags: javascript

So here is my javascript part of Sliding puzzle project. It doesn't seem to be checking if tiles are adjacent to empty tile before swapping. I changed code several times and now can't see the problem. I'd appreciate any help.

```js
let count = 0;
const body = document.body;
const puzzleOverlay = document.getElementById('puzzle-overlay'); //Create overlay when puzzle modal is open
const menuOverlay = document.getElementById('menu-overlay'); //Create overlay when menu modal is open
const modal = document.getElementById('modal'); //Get menu modal
const menuButton = document.getElementById('menu-button'); //Get the button to open menu modal
const close = document.getElementsByClassName('close-button')[0]; //Get the element that closes modal
const imgModal = document.getElementById('imgModal'); //Get complete puzzle modal
const imgButton = document.getElementById('show-img'); //Get the button to open image modal
const newGame = document.getElementById('new-game'); //Get a new game button
let movesCounter = document.querySelector('#moves'); //Get moves counter button


//Initial puzzle array
const initialPuzzle = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 0] //0 for the empty tile
];

//Check if puzzle is solved
function isPuzzleSolved() {
  let tileNumbers = [];

  //Collect the numbers of tiles
  for (let row = 1; row <= 3; row++) {
    for (let column = 1; column <= 3; column++) {
      const tile = document.getElementById('tile' + row + column);
      tileNumbers.push(parseInt(tile.textContent));
    }
  }

  //Check if tiles are in sequence
  for (let i = 0; i < tileNumbers.length - 1; i++) {
    if (tileNumbers[i] !== i + 1) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  //The last tile is an empty one
  return tileNumbers[tileNumbers - 1] === '9';
}

//Change puzzle to array
function isSolvable(puzzle) {
  const flatPuzzle = puzzle.flat();
  const size = flatPuzzle.length;

  let inversions = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      if (flatPuzzle[i] !== 0 && flatPuzzle[j] !== 0 && flatPuzzle[i] > flatPuzzle[j]) {
        inversions++;
      }
    }
  }

  return inversions % 2 === 0;
}

//Atach event listeners to tiles
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  newGame.addEventListener('click', function() {
    shufflePuzzle();
    count = 0;
    movesCounter.innerHTML = 'Moves: ' + count;
  });

  for (let row = 1; row <= 3; row++) {
    for (let column = 1; column <= 3; column++) {
      const tile = document.getElementById('tile' + row + column);
      tile.addEventListener('click', (function(currentRow, currentColumn) {
        return function() {
          chooseTile(currentRow, currentColumn);
          moveTiles('tile' + currentRow + currentColumn, 'tile33');

          //Check if puzzle is solved
          if (isPuzzleSolved()) {
            alert('Congratulations! You solved the puzzle!');
          }
        };
      })(row, column));
    }
  }
});

function moveTiles(tile1, tile2) {
  const tile1Element = document.getElementById(tile1);
  const tile2Element = document.getElementById(tile2);

  // Swap the src attribute of the two tiles
  const tempSrc = tile1Element.src;
  tile1Element.src = tile2Element.src;
  tile2Element.src = tempSrc;

  // Swap data attributes to update tile positions
  [tile1Element.dataset.row, tile2Element.dataset.row] = [tile2Element.dataset.row, tile1Element.dataset.row];
  [tile1Element.dataset.column, tile2Element.dataset.column] = [tile2Element.dataset.column, tile1Element.dataset.column];

  //Count moves
  count++;
  movesCounter.innerHTML = 'Moves: ' + count;
}

//Nested loops for each cell of the table
function shufflePuzzle() {
  if (!isSolvable(initialPuzzle)) {
    alert('Puzzle is not solvable! Please start new game!');
    return;
  }

  document.getElementById('moves').innerHTML = 'Moves: 0';

  for (let row = 1; row <= 3; row++) {
    for (let column = 1; column <= 3; column++) {

      let secondRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
      let secondCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);

      if (row !== secondRow || column !== secondCol) {
        const tile1 = "tile" + row + column;
        const tile2 = "tile" + secondRow + secondCol;
        moveTiles(tile1, tile2);
      }
    }
  }
}

newGame.addEventListener('click', shufflePuzzle);

function chooseTile(row, column) {
  const tile = document.getElementById("tile" + row + column);
  const tileClass = tile.className;

  // Get the positions of the adjacent tiles
  const leftTile = document.getElementById("tile" + row + (column - 1));
  const rightTile = document.getElementById("tile" + row + (column + 1));
  const topTile = document.getElementById("tile" + (row - 1) + column);
  const bottomTile = document.getElementById("tile" + (row + 1) + column);

  // Check if any adjacent tile is the empty tile
  const isLeftEmpty = leftTile && leftTile.className.includes("tile9");
  const isRightEmpty = rightTile && rightTile.className.includes("tile9");
  const isTopEmpty = topTile && topTile.className.includes("tile9");
  const isBottomEmpty = bottomTile && bottomTile.className.includes("tile9");

  // Check if the current tile can be moved
  if (tileClass.includes("tile9") && (isLeftEmpty || isRightEmpty || isTopEmpty || isBottomEmpty)) {
    if (isLeftEmpty) {
      moveTiles("tile" + row + column, "tile" + row + (column - 1));
    } else if (isRightEmpty) {
      moveTiles("tile" + row + column, "tile" + row + (column + 1));
    } else if (isTopEmpty) {
      moveTiles("tile" + row + column, "tile" + (row - 1) + column);
    } else if (isBottomEmpty) {
      moveTiles("tile" + row + column, "tile" + (row + 1) + column);
    }
  } else {
    console.log(`No adjacent empty tile found for (${row}, ${column})`);
  }
}

//Open menu modal if button is clicked
menuButton.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = 'block';

  // Disable the body
  body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  menuOverlay.style.display = 'block';
};

//Close menu modal when close (x) element is clicked
close.onclick = function(event) {
  modal.style.display = 'none';

  // Enable the body
  body.style.overflow = 'auto';
  menuOverlay.style.display = 'none';
};

//Open image modal if button is clicked
imgButton.onclick = function() {
  imgModal.style.display = 'block';

  // Disable the body
  body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  puzzleOverlay.style.display = 'block';
};

//Close image modal when user clicks on image
imgModal.onclick = function(event) {
  imgModal.style.display = 'none';

  // Enable the body
  body.style.overflow = 'auto';
  puzzleOverlay.style.display = 'none';
};

movesCounter.addEventListener('click', function() {
  count += 1;
  movesCounter.innerHTML = 'Moves: ' + count;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="description" content="Sliding 3x3 puzzle game with objective is to rearrange the tiles to make a complete image in as little moves as possible." />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" />
  <title>Sliding Puzzle</title>
  <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Sliding Puzzle</h1>
    <!--Menu Modal-->
    <div class="menu-modal" id="modal">
      <h2 class="menu-title">Main Menu</h2>
      <span class="close-button">
          <a href="#" id="close"
            ><i
              class="fa-sharp fa-regular fa-rectangle-xmark fa-2xl"
              style="color: #2f97a0"
            ></i
          ></a>
        </span>
      <div class="sub-menu">
        <div class="menu-subtitle">Objective</div>
        <div class="menu-text">
          <p>
            Solve a puzzle by rearranging tiles in correct order to make a complete image.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-subtitle">Rules</div>
        <div class="menu-text">
          <p>
            <span class="bold">New Game:</span> At the beginning of the game click "New Game" to shuffle the tiles.
          </p>
          <p>
            <span class="bold">Tile Movement:</span> The game is played on a grid with square tiles. There is one empty space that allows tiles to slide into it.
          </p>
          <p>
            <span class="bold">Tile Sliding:</span> Tiles can be moved horizontally or vertically into the empty space. Only one tile can occupy the empty space at a time, and tiles cannot jump over one another.
          </p>
          <p>
            <span class="bold">Winning:</span> The game is considered solved or won when the tiles are in the correct order to make a complete image.
          </p>
          <p>
            <span class="bold">Reset and Shuffle:</span> To reset the puzzle to its initial state click on "New Game" to shuffle the tiles to start over.
          </p>
          <p>
            <span class="bold">Show/ close complete puzzle:</span> To see complete puzzle image click on "Show image", to close - click on image
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu-overlay"></div>
    <!--End of modal-->
    <div class="game-container">
      <div class="buttons">
        <!--A button to open modal-->
        <button id="menu-button">Menu</button>
        <!--New game button-->
        <button id="new-game">New Game</button>
        <!--A button to show complete puzzle image-->
        <button id="show-img">Show image</button>
        <!--Moves counter-->
        <div id="moves">Moves: 0</div>
      </div>
      <!--Complete puzzle modal-->
      <div class="complete-puzzle" id="imgModal">
        <img src="assets/images/coast-of-galway360.jpg" alt="Photo of Galway coast on a sunny day" />
      </div>
      <div id="puzzle-overlay"></div>
      <div id="puzzle-container">
        <img id="tile11" class="tile tile1" data-row="1" data-column="1" src="assets/images/1.jpg" alt="Puzzle tile with clouds" />
        <img id="tile12" class="tile tile2" data-row="1" data-column="2" src="assets/images/2.jpg" alt="Puzzle tile with clouds" />
        <img id="tile13" class="tile tile3" data-row="1" data-column="3" src="assets/images/3.jpg" alt="Puzzle tile with clouds" />
        <img id="tile21" class="tile tile4" data-row="2" data-column="1" src="assets/images/4.jpg" alt="Puzzle tile with clouds and ocean" />
        <img id="tile22" class="tile tile5" data-row="2" data-column="2" src="assets/images/5.jpg" alt="Puzzle tile with clouds and ocean" />
        <img id="tile23" class="tile tile6" data-row="2" data-column="3" src="assets/images/6.jpg" alt="Puzzle tile with clouds and ocean" />
        <img id="tile31" class="tile tile7" data-row="3" data-column="1" src="assets/images/7.jpg" alt="Puzzle tile with beach sand and rocks" />
        <img id="tile32" class="tile tile8" data-row="3" data-column="2" src="assets/images/8.jpg" alt="Puzzle tile with beach sand and rocks" />
        <img id="tile33" class="tile tile9" data-row="3" data-column="3" src="assets/images/empty-tile9.jpg" alt="Empty, white puzzle tile" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Footer-->
    <footer class="footer">
      <ul class="footer-icons">
        <li>
          <a href="https://github.com/violaberg" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="Visit my GitHub page (opens in a new tab)"><i class="fa-brands fa-github fa-xl" style="color: #000000"></i
            ></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/photos_by_vb/" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="Visit my Instagram page (opens in a new tab)"><i
                class="fa-brands fa-instagram fa-xl"
                style="color: #000000"
              ></i
            ></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/viola-bergere-5a668699/" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="Visit my LinkedIn page (opens in a new tab)"><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin fa-xl" style="color: #000000"></i
            ></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p class="copyright">&copy;reated by violaberg</p>
    </footer>
    <!--End of footer-->
  </div>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/284fde1047.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I had working puzzle but it kept giving me console error I couldn't fix for some reason so I change the code entirely which wasn't very smart as know I got stuck at this error for all tiles: **No adjacent empty tile found for (1, 2)** I tried to change up moveTiles and ChooseTile functions but nothing seems to fix the issue.

Comment: FYI, you don't need the IIFE pattern when you use `let` rather than `var` in your `for` loops.

Comment: I've converted your code to an executable snippet. Can you add the CSS and image URLs so the grid will be shown properly?

Comment: The problem is `tileClass.includes("tile9") &&`. That will only be true if they click on the empty tile, but they're clicking on the tile next to the empty tile.

Comment: PS: Use `.classList.includes()` instead of `.className.includes()`. The letter will match substrings, e.g. `includes("tile")` will match `tile9`.

Comment: @Barmar These didn't resolve my issue but there was a line in moveTiles function that was causing error and wasn't actually needed at all. Thank you for your help, I learned something new!